# Moment.js Timezone is not converting properly

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to convert some dates and times to different timezones and Moment.js is not functioning properly for this. I have read through the documentation and I have seen numerous examples and it seems I am doing this correctly, but it is not properly converting Los Angeles time to New York time. What am I doing wrong?

JS

```
var timeSelected = 2020/12/04 17:00;
var clientTz = America/Los_Angeles
var presenterTz = America/New_York

var momentTz = moment.tz(timeSelected, clientTz).tz(presenterTz).format( 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm' );
```

Comment: That's not valid javascript in your example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const timeSelected = '2020/12/04 17:00';
const clientTz = 'America/Los_Angeles';
const presenterTz = 'America/New_York';

const momentTz = moment
    .tz(timeSelected, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm', clientTz)
    .tz(presenterTz)
    .format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm');
```

There might be argument between time and timezone in moment.tz function. You must pass format of source string if it's not default.

Comment: Thank you, @Focus RS! This made it work. Specifically, the addition of the time formatting here: .tz(timeSelected, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm', clientTz). Now it is properly calculating the time differences between Los Angeles, New York, and everywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Check below. I have did some changes and added the proper libraries. SOmetime if you have not included moment-timezone-with-data.js this does not work for some timezones. I have changed the input format, if you want to change the format to your format from question you have to use

> .tz(timeSelected, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm', clientTz)

```js
var timeSelected = '2020-12-04 17:00';
var clientTz = 'America/Los_Angeles'
var presenterTz = 'America/New_York'

var momentTz = moment.tz(timeSelected, clientTz).tz(presenterTz).format( 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm' );

console.log(momentTz)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.32/moment-timezone.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.32/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi @A Paul, yes, your example works here. I'm not sure why it's not converting properly on my setup. These are the cdns I used below...   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.32/moment-timezone.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.32/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>

Comment: Hi @grahamfk45c I have also changed the input variable format var timeSelected = '2020-12-04 17:00';. Try that, or you have to use .tz(timeSelected, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm', clientTz). Otherwise you libraries looks good.

Comment: @A Paul, yes, I saw that. For some reason it's not properly calculating the timezones on my end. It keeps saying that New York is five hours behind Los Angeles and that is simply not true. Thanks for the input!